# how to start only one job in a task in spring cloud dataflow

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have a simple task which has 2 jobs. When I run the task Job 1 and Job 2 run one after another. How can I configure it in a way so that when I pass the job name only that job runs?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from having one task for job1 and another task for job2? This would solve your problem by design. Now to answer your question, see my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually currently we are using spring batch admin. We have about 130 jobs. And we create jars which contain 10-20 jobs in one jar. We have configured them via XML. We are planning to remove the schedulers and convert them into tasks. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot executes all jobs in the application context at startup (See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-batch-applications.html#howto-execute-spring-batch-jobs-on-startup)). If you want to execute only one job, you need to specify its name using the `spring.batch.job.names` property.

In your case, you can add a task argument and specify which job want to run. For example: if your task contains two jobs `job1` and `job2`, you can add the task argument `--spring.batch.job.names=job1` to run only `job1`:

[image: sct-argument]

Make sure to add `--` to the key. The command that will be executed by SCDF server should be something like:

```
2018-09-10 12:23:45.932  INFO 57560 --- [nio-9393-exec-1] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher      : Command to be executed: java -jar myjob.jar --spring.batch.job.names=job1 --spring.cloud.task.executionid=1
```

With this argument, only `job1` should be executed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for this. It worked. Huge help. Also, any idea how I can order my jobs? a similar tag where i can maybe run job2 first then job1. --spring.batch.job.names=job2,job1 runs 1 first then 2 as job1 is defined before job2. Thanks.